Prove symmetry of probabilities given random variables are iid and have (not absolutely) continuous cdf
Let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables in $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ s.t. their distributions are continuous. Denote common distribution as $$F(y) := F_{Y_1}(y) = F_{Y_2}(y) = \cdots$$
For $m = 1, 2, ...$ and $i \le m$, define $$A_{i,m} := (\max\{Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_m\} = Y_i), B_m := A_{m,m}$$

Is it really that $$P(B_m) = P(A_{m-1,m}) = ... = P(A_{2,m}) = P(A_{1,m})$$
and hence $$P(B_m) = 1/m?$$
I guess $(A_{(i,m)})_{i \le m}$'s pairwise disjoint, for a fixed m and that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} P(A_{(i,m)}) = P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} A_{(i,m)}) = 1$$

Case1 - Assuming the random variables are absolutely continuous:
Let $f$ denote common pdf.
$$P(B_m) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} f_{Y_1, ..., Y_n} (y_1, ..., y_n) dy_1dy_2...dy_{n-1}dy_n$$
By independence, we have
$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} f_{Y_1}(y_1) \cdots f_{Y_n}(y_n) dy_1dy_2...dy_{n-1}dy_n$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} [\int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} \int_{-\infty}^{y_n} f(y_1) \cdots f(y_{n-1}) dy_1dy_2...dy_{n-1}] f(y_n) dy_n$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n) ... F(y_n)] f(y_n) dy_n$$
By identical distribution,
$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n) ... F(y_n)] f(y_n) dy_n$$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} f(y_n) dy_n$$
Let
$$I = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} f(y_n) dy_n$$
Then
$$I = [F(y_n)]^{n-1} F(y_n)|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} (n-1) f(y_n) dy_n$$
$$ = [(1)(1) - (0)(0)] - \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} (n-1) f(y_n) dy_n = 1-(n-1)I$$
$$\therefore, I = 1/n. \ \text{QED}$$
Case2 - Even if the pdfs don't exist, can I actually still evaluate the same way?
I mean, it's still $u=F(y_n)$ but then instead of $du=f(y_n)dy_n$, it's $du=dF(y_n)$. I think the proof still works word-for-word.
For example, here's the (non-absolutely) continuous version of proof for the last part starting from the $I$:
Let
$$I = \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} dF(y_n)$$
Then
$$I = u \times v - \int v \times du$$
$$ = [[F(y_n)]^{n-1}] \times [F(y_n)]|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)] \times [[F(y_n)]^{n-2} (n-1) dF(y_n)]$$
$$ = [(1)(1) - (0)(0)] - \int_{\mathbb R} [F(y_n)]^{n-1} (n-1) dF(y_n) = 1-(n-1)I$$
$$\therefore, I = 1/n. \ \text{QED}$$

Is there an essential difference with this question?

@drhab $dF(y)$ instead of $fdy$

By "continuous" distribution, I assume you mean the distribution without atoms, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=a)=0$ for all real $a$.
First, the probability of ties is zero, as
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y_1=Y_2)=\int \mathbb{P}(Y_2=x)dF_{Y_1}(x)=0
$$
because the probability inside is always zero.
Secondly,
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y_m>Y_1,...,Y_{m-1})=\int \mathbb{P}(Y_1\le x,...,Y_{m-1}\le x)dF_{Y_m}(x)=
\int F(x)^{m-1}dF(x)=1/m.
$$

yeah so you agree the parts with $f(y_n)dy_n$ can just be replaced with $dF(y_n)$ word-for-word, and the proof still works?
